# MySQL service cannot be started

Tags: mysql, centos

I've created a snapshot on an old server and used it to create a new cloud server. The old server was created several years ago and it works perfect fine. However the MySQL service couldn't be started on this new server. I don't remember the installation detail of this old server. I'm trying to figure out the reason why MySQL service can't be started. Here's the information I got. Please help me find out what's going on. Thank you very much.

[image]

[image]

Comment: check mysql directory and its sub directory  permission. Also try to run mysql with user root.

Comment: The permission is all good. I also tried root user. Nothing happened. Thank you for your prompt reply. I just reinstalled MySQL.

Comment: Reading the mysql error log should explain the issue.